# Whenever gem not working for every 1.day tasks but working for other arguments in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, whenever

I am using whenever gem and I have written a rake task to send emails.
In my schedule.rb when I use this code

```
set :environment, "development"
set :output, {:error => "log/cron_error_log.log",
:standard =>"log/cron_log.log"}

every :day, :at => '11:20pm' do 
  rake "send_daily_reports"
end
```

I am not getting mails but when i use something like this

```
every 5.minutes do
  rake "send_daily_reports"
end
```

I get mails for 5 every minutes.

I tried replacing

```
every :day
```

with

```
every 1.day
```

but still its not working.
I have followed every step. When I pull the code into the cloud I use the command

```
whenever -w
```

to update the crontab and then restart the server. I thought that there might be an issue with the linux system time.But when i used the 
    date 
command in the terminal I got the correct date and time.I also checked the cron_error log but there are no errors logged. Can anyone please help me out here?

Comment: what does `crontab -l` report?

Comment: What does send_daily_reports look like? Is it possible that there is some kind of time zone issue that prevents send_daily_reports from having any data to report on at 11:20pm?

Comment: @msergeant I recieved the mail at 4.20 am when the time set was "11.20pm". So I guess there was an error with the timezone setting in linux. I changed the timezone and now its working. Previously the default timezone was in utc and i thought the system would automatically set itself according to the timezone. Once I changed the time zone it is working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recieved the mail at `4.20 am` when the time set was `11.20 pm`. So I guess `timezone` setting was set to `utc` default in `amazon linux`.

I changed the `timezone` and now its working and I referred this link http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-time.html

Previously the default timezone was in `utc` and I thought the system would automatically set itself according to the `timezone`. Once I changed the time zone it is working now.